# Cleanup some bad MediaWiki questions

Tags: discussion, clean-up

I'm a long-time MediaWiki user and I monitor [MediaWiki-related questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki) to make sure they eventually have an answer.

There are some low-quality questions which just clutter my todo list of unanswered questions for no gain, because I believe they are impossible to answer. This includes:

- low quality questions where it's impossible to figure out what the real problem was and how to solve it;
- questions which might be solvable, but the asker disappeared without providing key information (e.g. configuration issues with no info on current configuration);
- questions which basically amount to "please code an extension for me";
- duplicates of questions with good answers.

Usually downvoting is enough (and can cause autodeletion), but in some cases I flagged the questions and the flags aged away (often) or were declined (rarely). Yet I'm convinced those questions won't help anyone. Can someone give a look?

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289452/how-do-i-get-an-edit-token-for-my-java-program-to-write-pages-to-a-mediawiki-al</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918461/mediawiki-plugin-extension-for-notification</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934575/can-i-change-an-ip-address-to-show-a-domain-name</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133690/mediawiki-email-configuration-in-localsettings-php-is-discarded</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221925/php-curl-get-wikipedia-infobox</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944277/cant-get-edit-token-using-mediawiki-api</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397723/mediawiki-mw-collapsible-unable-to-collapse-in-mobile</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833745/mediawiki-short-url-htacess-method-vs-apache-method</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947751/client-side-query-mediawiki-for-items-based-on-the-categories-their-parents-are</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878129/installed-wikidata-in-mediawiki-now-db-error</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967819/sending-emails-through-mediawiki-on-azure</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059107/can-i-upload-files-on-the-onedrive-using-linux-terminal</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281225/error-in-bugzilla-reporting-extension-notice-unserialize-error-at-offset-0-o</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671909/searching-for-media-in-mediawiki-visualeditor</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519856/php-5-3-3-ldap-support</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189267/how-to-add-mathematical-formulas-plugin-in-ckeditor-gem</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190151/android-studio-deploy-files-with-the-app</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420258/getting-all-properties-from-wikipedia-infobox-java</s>

Comment: The SE meta-filter lists "2 users following" but unfortunately SO's own tag does not appear to have such an entry. Maybe there are not enough field experts?

Comment: @Jongware there are not many, but we are enough to answer pretty much anything which is answerable. Among the [top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mediawiki/topusers) you can see even Brion Vibber, as well as several core developers. Most focus on recent questions because these are where rep comes from. ;)

Comment: I asked because it seems that for a lot of these (if not all – you see, I cannot even tell) explicit field expertise is required. It may be the reason your "flags aged away (often) or were declined (rarely)" – moderators are wary of intervening if they are not sure if something is a good question or not.

Comment: @Jongware ah yes, that's definitely true. Most MediaWiki people are not active in the meta/moderation side and vice versa.

Comment: Consider adding what you want to happen in each case, and (unless you are really sure it's obvious) why.

Comment: @Nemo apart from you (I can see a lot of suggested edits and flagging to close) and a couple of others casting close votes - they are all just ageing away. I've dropped a link to this post in the [SOCVR chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) - I'm sure some of them will be up for offering advice/helping out.

Comment: To follow up on what @Jon said: [Closey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4424245/closey) (the bot) says `(╯°□°)╯` Which I think means he'd be happy for you to stop by. (It's pretty quiet right now, but it should pick up tomorrow morning.)

Comment: @theB thanks, I read the docs but I'm not sure how to use the bot. I probably don't have sufficient rep.

Comment: Sorry, if there was any confusion. Closey just monitors people through the close vote queue and helps coordinate efforts to clear the queue. All of the decisions about whether something should be closed are left to the people. I see that things are already getting crossed off the list. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They have all been closed now.

Feel free to drop by [the Close Vote Reviewers' chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) again any time and leave a few [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) if something else needs cleaning up.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to do so.